# Jquery .load() shows messed up content on refresh. How to fix that?

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net

I have a main page that loads a content of a div:

```
    var content = $("#content_layout");
    //some code here
    content.load("claim_form.aspx?claim_no=" + file_number);
```

The claim_form.aspx has a drop down, and based on that drop down it should show the apropriate input fields. I set the index to be 1 and automatically load the first set of inputs. Here is some code to explain it better:

```
$("#request_type").change(function(e) {
    index = document.getElementById("request_type").selectedIndex;
    if (index == "0") {
        variable_content(1000);
        hide_all(900);
        show_div("#invoice_payment_button_layout", 900);
        real_index = "1";
    }
    else if (index == "1") {
        variable_content(1000);
        hide_all(900);
        show_div("#void_check_button_layout", 900);
        real_index = "2";
// and so on......
```

When I load the page for the first time, it works perfectly; however, when I hit F5 or access the page again via url, I see ALL the input fields. As if the index was every singe number....

I'm using IE7 for this (company requirement)... 
Can anyone tell me how to fix the problem? So when I hit F5 or access the page again it does not show me all the stuff?

EDIT: 
More Code:

```
//This is the first line
$(document).ready(function() {
//define some variables blah blah
hide_all(1); //I created this function (not sure if one exists so i specify)
```

then later:

```
function hide_all(speed) {
    $("#comment_box_layout").slideUp(speed);
    $("#invoice_payment_button_layout").slideUp(speed);
    $("#deductible_recovery_request_layout").slideUp(speed);
//so on with all the divs
}
```

Maybe it will be easier now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling the hide_all() method on $(document).ready? It sounds like there is some funny CSS caching, so maybe by always hiding everything when the document is ready, you could set a clean base state.

Comment: I hide all the divs in the beginning. Check the code I added to the original post.

Comment: Two ideas: Replace $(document).ready( with $(window).load(

Second: Make sure all references to CSS are made before including your JavaScript.

The first one may slow things down a bit, but if it fixes the problem it helps to sort out the cause.

Comment: Yeah... 2 things:
1: I put all the CSS above the JS and nothing has changed :/
2: I replaced the $(document).ready with $(window).load and now it doesn't even work on the frist try or refresh.

Comment: I'd just be taking shots in the dark at this points. At this point, I would just simplify the code as much as possible (e.g. replacing all animations with simple hide/show calls, making sure the markup is totally valid).

Comment: I think i found the source of the problem (Besides IE). The page is loaded dynamically via .load(). When I view the page that is being loaded normally the jquery works fine....

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mark this old post as solved. After I simplified the code things started working. That was some seriously old and weird code :)

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess -- it is probably a combination of style-sheet problems, and that `change` not firing on the initial page load of refresh.

Have you verified that the `chahce` actuall fire when you refresh the page?

Style sheet problem: what is the inital state of your divs? display or hidden?   Try to make them all initially hidden via style sheet and see if it goes away.

Comment: I have a function that hides all the divs right on top. So initially they are all hidden and then shown depending on that dropdown. I also realized that i have:

    $(document).ready(function() {

on the top. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Which part of the code do you want me to show? the Top or the hide_all function?